# laravel 5.5 axios on shared hosting sub folder api not working

Tags: laravel

I created brand new laravel 5.5 project on localhost all is working, api, route, auth etc..

I uploaded it on my sharedhosting by following 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4 tutorial, and all works. except on axios request on app.js

It say

**https://domainname/oauth/clients not found
https://domainname/oauth/clients not found
https://domainname/oauth/tokens not found
https://domainname/oauth/scopes not found**

My work around is to config the public/js/app.js code by adding subdomain.

```
 axios.get('[subdomain]/oauth/clients') <-- add manually
```

and it's working but any simple solution for this directory problem ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem and this is how I solved it:

in my main php page i've add my base url like this:

```
<script>
 var flagsUrl = '{{ env('APP_URL') }}'; //this is the url from .env file
</script>
```

so you can change to your js file like this:

```
axios.get(flagsUrl + '/oauth/clients');
```

Comment: I think there's other simple solution for this beside from changing app js line of codes. like changing directory or something.

Comment: whats your local url  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set base url of axios in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

```
windows.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://yoursubdomain'
```

Example:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
window.axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://subdomain';
```

Then you can use:

```
axios.get('oauth/clients');
```